# Improving performance of a firebase node js function

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

My node js code usually runs in less than 0.5seconds locally but when I deploy on firebase function it sometimes take up to 3 seconds to 5 seconds to return the response I want. is there a way to fix this perfomance issue? the problem is I do all the computation in a single request function because I need to parse text from that request and use it in my code but I couldn't figure out any other way to fix it. any suggestions would be appreciated and thanks in advance

```
exports.Response = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
   const original = req.query.text;
   var returned = original.split(',');
   var startLat= returned[0];
   var startLong = returned[1];
   var endLat = returned[2];
   var endLong = returned[3];
   var maxDistance = returned[4];
   var output = binding.Main(startLat, startLong, endLat, endLong, Number(maxDistance));
   var Response = output.split(' ');
   var Array = [];
   for(i = 0; i<Response.length ; i++)
   {
      Array.push(Response[i]);
   }
   var data = {};
   data.table = [];
   var obj = 
   {
   Start: Array[0]
   }
   data.table.push(obj);
   for (i=1; i < Array.length-1 ;i+=7)
   {
      var obj = 
      {
         transportType: Array[i],
         Price: Array[i+1],
         Type: Array[i+2],
         startLatitude: Array[i+3],
         startLongitude: Array[i+4],
         endLatitude: Array[i+5],
         endLongitude: Array[i+6] 
      }  
      data.table.push(obj);

   }
   var obj = {
      TotalPrice: Array[Array.length-1]
   }
   data.table.push(obj);
     res.status(200).json({
      data
  })
 });
```

I know code is unprofessional but am still new to node js and addons so I tried my best to get the required output. any suggestions/notes would be taken and appreciated. Also if any further code/explanation is required please let me know.

Comment: The delay you encounter after deploying your Cloud function is most probably not caused by your code but by the cold start ("Functions are stateless, and the execution environment is often initialized from scratch, which is called a cold start"). See more details and possible improvement tips at: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v3eG9xpzNXM, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IOXrwFqR6kY, https://medium.com/@duhroach/improving-cloud-function-cold-start-time-2eb6f5700f6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Helping Renaud Tarnec's reply to be posted as an answer:

The delay you encounter after deploying your Cloud function is most probably not caused by your code but by the cold start ("Functions are stateless, and the execution environment is often initialized from scratch, which is called a cold start"). See more details and possible improvement tips at: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips, https://youtube.com/watch?v=v3eG9xpzNXM, https://youtube.com/watch?v=IOXrwFqR6kY, https://medium.com/@duhroach/improving-cloud-function-cold-start-time-2eb6f5700f6